# how to make icon red with nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.videoicons i:nth-child(1) { color:red; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<ul class="videoicons">
    <li><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i><span>1K</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <span>0</span></li>
</ul>
```

With the coding I have, I expected that I can make only the first icon red. However, the outcome shows me the first and second icons turn red.

And I tried `.videoicons li:nth-child(1){color:red;}`. It makes `1k` and the first icon red.

I am trying to make only the first icon red by using `nth-child`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```css
.videoicons i:nth-child(1) { color:red; }
```

To:

```css
.videoicons li:nth-child(1) i { color:red; }
```

This way you're specifically selecting the first list item and only coloring the icon there. Updated example:

```css
.videoicons li:nth-child(1) i { color:red; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<ul class="videoicons">
    <li><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i><span>1K</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <span>0</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're going to go through the trouble of writing the OP's code for them, you might as well edit the question with a working snippet so that it's on-topic...

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've fixed the typo and edited OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `i` after `li:nth-child()`

```css
.videoicons li:nth-child(1) i {
    color:red;
}
```